# How to host multiple domains and subdomains on single AWS EC2 instance

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf, amazon-route53

I am trying to set up 2 domains (domain1.com and domain2.com) with a few subdomains (app.domain1.com) in AWS and run them on single instance (Amazon Linux, PHP, MySQL).

I have set up 3 hosted zones in AWS Route53 with following configurations.

> **Hosted zone 1:**
> domain1.com
> Type A
> 52.108.XX.YY
>
> **Hosted Zone 2**
> domain2.com
> Type A
> 52.108.XX.YY
>
> **Hosted Zone 3**
> app.domain1.com
> Type A
> 52.108.XX.YY

Additionally, I have added following code to the http.conf file in VirtualHost tag.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
     ServerName domain1.com   
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain1"   
     ErrorLog "logs/domain1-error_log"  
     CustomLog "logs/domain1-access_log" common  
     </VirtualHost>
     
     <VirtualHost *:80>   
     ServerName domain2.com   
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain2"  
     ErrorLog "logs/domain2-error_log"  
     CustomLog "logs/domain2-access_log" common  
     </VirtualHost>
     
     <VirtualHost *:80>  
     ServerName app.domain1.com   
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/app"  
     ErrorLog "logs/app.domain1-error_log"  
     CustomLog "logs/app.domain1-access_log" common  
     </VirtualHost>
```

However, only domain1.com and domain2.com are getting resolved. When I visit app.domain1.com, it gives me a "can't find server" error. Please help how to setup the subdomain - is there problem in Hosted Zone setup or httpd.conf?

Comment: Are you sure your app.domain1.com is resolving to 52.108.XX.YY try ping it again.

Comment: Can you provide the three domains so I can check the issue?

Comment: You are correct, it is not resolving to correct IP address. Do you think I have to add subdomain on Dreamhost (registrar) and provide it with NS of Hosted Zone 3?

Comment: pradyotghate.com
dev.pradyotghate.com

Comment: that is the reason why it is not resolving add a A-record to app.domain1.com to point to 52.108.XX.YY and it will start working your configuration is correct. You do not have change any NS for this. Just add a Subdomain.

Comment: Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw0-L28_lks

Comment: Added subdomain on Dreamhost. Waiting for it to propagate. Will check then. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so after about 2 hours of reading up various sites and tinkering, I am all set. Here is how to do this.

Basically, you should not have more than 1 hosted zone (HZ) per domain name, otherwise things are really going to be bad. If you have more than 1 HZ for a domain name, please delete the one that was created for the subdomain.

Each HZ will have 4 records -

> Following two records are created by default. Do not edit/delete them.
> **NS** - This is the name server record. If AWS Route53 is not your registrar, use `ns-servernumber.awsdns-number.com.` and other three (4 total) records to change name servers for your registrar.
> **SOA** - Let this record be. DO NOT TOUCH THIS.
>
> Create following two Record Set (blue button).
> **A** - Leave *Name* blank. Select `A-IPv4 address` for *Type*. In *Value* enter the IP address for your Elastic Load Balancer or EC2 instance.
> **CNAME** - Add * (asterisks/wildcard) in the *name* field. Select `CNAME` from the drop down for *Type* In *Value* enter the domain name.

Now create the `http.conf` file and structure virtual hosts like I have in the question.

Things should work now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the tutorial on this link: http://brianshim.com/webtricks/host-multiple-sites-amazon-ec2/

A common error, according to the link, is:

> Did it work? If not, here is one possible cause. There might be
>   another configuration file interfering with this one. Check for
>   another .conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d.  Often your primary
>   httpd.conf will include another .conf file in this directory. Make
>   sure it doesn’t have some Virtual Host settings which are interfering
>   with yours.

After you set the configurations, you should run:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing sharing the article. Read it. But it seems like a pre-Route 53 article. It prescribes directly pointing domain to IP address, not a recommended practice by AWS since it is not scalable with Elastic Load Balancers in future.
Need guidance on making this work with Route 53 managing NS.

Comment: No other virtual host setting files. Did restart Apache.

Comment: @PradyotGhate In your question you say you are setting up A records in Route53 to point directly to IP addresses. So there is no difference here in using Route53 versus any other DNS service. Your comment about Route53 being "scalable with Elastic Load Balancers in future" doesn't really seem to be relevant to the discussion. Yes you can use Route53 aliases to point root domains to ELBs in the future, but right now you are just using A records like you would on any other DNS service like Godaddy which is referenced in the linked article.

Comment: Correct, it is not relevant today. But I want to keep that option (add ELB and point the Type A to EBL instead of EC2 instance) open. That's why using Route53 and not directly resolving domain name to IP address. Please tell me if I am not thinking about this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done installing **Apache HTTP Server** on **AWS-EC2** instance and configuring **VirtualHost** for each DNS or Sub-DNS as suggested by an [Amazonian](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/profile.jspa?userID=147543)

For brevity read this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=58768) discussion, this official [example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) and [techrepublic post](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/rewriting-urls-to-host-multiple-domains-on-a-single-ip-address-with-apache/).

---

Hope this helped!